# pyplot savefig raises OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I tried to save a matplotlib figure to a file, I keep getting Bad file description error. My code is as follow:

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\\users\\mutas\\documents\\')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.text(0.5,0.5, 'some text')

if os.path.isfile('c.png'):
    plt.savefig('c.png')
```

When run, it raises the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: <built-in method write of _io.BufferedWriter object at 
0x0C7E0360> returned a result with an error set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: <built-in method write of _io.BufferedWriter object at 
0x0C7E0360> returned a result with an error set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: <built-in method write of _io.BufferedWriter object at 
0x0C7E0360> returned a result with an error set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: <built-in method write of _io.BufferedWriter object at 
0x0C7E0360> returned a result with an error set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: <built-in method write of _io.BufferedWriter object at 
0x0C7E0360> returned a result with an error set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 410, in open_file_cm
yield fh
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 523, in print_png
self.figure.dpi, metadata=metadata)
SystemError: <built-in method write of _io.BufferedWriter object at 
0x0C7E0360> returned a result with an error set

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mutas\Documents\tpf01.py", line 8, in <module>
plt.savefig('c.png')
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 688, in savefig
res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 2097, in savefig
self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2075, in print_figure
**kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 523, in print_png
self.figure.dpi, metadata=metadata)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in 
__exit__
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 410, in open_file_cm
yield fh
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

What is happening here? Please note that this is not a new installation of matplotlib on the system. I have been using this for sometime now, and this issue suddenly started occurring.

Comment: Reinstalling matplotlib did not help.

Comment: All those `SystemError`s indicate a bug in CPython!

Comment: Would this also occur with a different file? Are you sure the file has been closed correctly?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, every file. I tried creating new files, and still the same result.